# Browserify jQuery Plugin Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, browserify, browserify-shim

I'm trying to browserify a jQuery plugin and getting this error in the browsers console all the time:
`Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'jquery'`

This is how my `package.json` part looks like:

```
"browserify": {
  "transform": [
    "browserify-shim"
  ]
},

"browser": {
  "jquery": "./app/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
  "jquery-timepicker-jt": "./app/vendor/jquery-timepicker-jt/jquery.timepicker.js"
},

"browserify-shim": {
  "jquery": {
    "exports": "$"
  },
  "jquery-timepicker-jt": {
    "depends": [ "jquery:jquery" ]
  },
}
```

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to include your index.js or similar entry file where you're requiring jQuery to understand what's going on. There's nothing wrong with your `package.json`. If you're using jQuery and the plugin in your code, you'd want to do one of these things, depending on how the plugin interacts with jQuery:

```
var $ = require('jquery');
window.$ = $; // If you need to access jQuery or `$.fn.timepicker` from the window object.
require('jquery-timepicker-jt');
```